# Februaryと入力するとエラーになってしまう。

Tags: vba

予定表を自作していて、２月の行の高さを変えようとして下記のとおりマクロを書き込みましたがエラーが出てしまいます。

```
Range("a6").AutoFilter 1, xlFilterAllDatesInPeriodFebruary, xlFilterDynamic

With Range("a6").CurrentRegion.Offset(1, 0)
.Resize(.Rows.Count - 1).RowHeight = 12.75
```

Februaryの箇所をJanuary等他の月にした場合はうまくいくのですが、Februaryだけどうしてもエラーになります、
FeburaryやFebraryを試してもダメでした。

Comment: 実際に表示されたエラーを質問に追記してください。また、コードはこれで全てでしょうか？

Comment: こんな記事 [AutoFilter for month of February](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/autofilter-for-month-of-february.449569/), [XlFilterAllDatesInPeriod & Variable not working!](https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/xlfilteralldatesinperiod-variable-not-working.509858/) が回答された内容に合っているのですが、一方正しいスペルの仕様資料 [XlDynamicFilterCriteria enumeration (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xldynamicfiltercriteria) やこんな記事 [VBA Excel - Using the xlFilterAllDatesInPeriod"Month" based on user input](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52324988/9014308) もあります。もしかしたらプラグラムの種類・版数かファイル形式やモード等に依存するのかも。

Answer (score 2):

2月の定数はFebrurayで登録されているようですので、Februrayでやってみて下さい。

Comment: ありがとうございます！できました！
他の皆さんもありがとうございます。

Comment: VBAって試してみるのも怖いですわぁ、何ですかこのバグ